# Verification that a statement is true or not.

Tags: proof-verification

Suppose that $gcd(ab,p^4)  = p^3$ then $p^3 |ab$. $p$ is prime.

$p^3 |ab \implies p^2|a$ and $p|b$

Is this last statement true?

The converse is true i believe.

EDIT.

$gcd(a,p^2) = p, gcd(b,p^2) = p. $

(This is a part of a larger proof, i am trying to disprove the first statement.)

Comment: Maybe you can come up with a specific example of p, a, and b for which it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's a long way from being true that $p^3 | ab \Rightarrow p^2 | a $ and $p | b$ (I think that's your question).  For example, take $a = p$ and $b = p^2$.

Comment: Thats great thanks. Could you suggest another method to disprove the supposition. Given the conditions in the edit?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to prove, but if $p^3$ is the greatest common divisor of $ab$ and $p^4$, then in particular $p^3$ must be a divisor of $ab$.  So it seems clear that the first statement is true.

Comment: I'm trying to prove that if $gcd(a,p^2) = p, gcd(b,p^2) = p. $ then $gcd(ab,p^4) = p^2$.

Comment: I see.  Well, if you write $a = px$ (where $p \nmid x$) and $b = py$ (where $p \nmid y$), then it looks pretty clear that $p^2 \mid ab$ but $p^3 \nmid ab$.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

$a=8,b=3,p=2$ is a counter example

Answer (score 0):

It's false: let $p,q$  be two distinct prime numbers. Let $a=p^3$; then $\gcd(p^3q,p^4)=p^3$, but $p\not\mid q$.